# Why does a friend function implemented in the class itself throws compilation error when the argument passed is not of the class type?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the code below:

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class String {
  char* data;
  int len;
  
public:
  String(char* str) : data(strdup(str)), len(strlen(data)) { }
  
  friend void display(String& str) {
    std::cout << str.data << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  String s = strdup("What");
  display(s);
  
  return 0;
}
```

---

The function `display(String&)` is a friend of the class `String` and is implemented inside the class itself.

The output is:

```
What
```

When I remove the arguments of the function `display()`, and call this function without any arguments, I get a compilation error:

> error: ‘display’ was not declared in this scope

I don't understand the behaviour of a friend function implemented inside the class itself. From my knowledge, as the function is not in the global scope, it shouldn't be accessible. But when the argument passed is of the type `String`, the code runs perfectly and prints the desired result.

What's a plausible explanation for this kind of behaviour?

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). You should post the non working code together with the compiler error, rather than code that does not have the error, read about [mcve]

Comment: `String s = strdup("What");` That's a memory leak. What happens with the memory that `strdup` allocates? Also note that `strdup` is not a standard C++ function. And in C++ you should almost never use C-style null-terminated strings yourself.

Comment: Also please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and  [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)